# How do i download a file with CA-VO

Tags: clipper

I'd like to download a file using HTTP. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I have investigated this further and have re-ordered my suggestions from last week as a result:

1. The class 'CHttp' in VO's 'Internet' library has a method GetFile ([the VO 2.5 "what's new" has a brief description on page 10](http://www.cavo.com/pubcavo/patch/2.5/whats_new_in_25b.pdf)). I've not tried it, though. You'll probably want something like this:

   ```
   local oSession as CHttp
   local lSuccess as logic

   oSession := CHttp{} 
   oSession:ConnectRemote("foo.example.com")      // Server domain name
   lSuccess := oSession:GetFile("bar/baz.pdf",;   // Remote filename
                               "c:\temp\baz.pdf",; // Local filename
                               lFailIfAlreadyExists)   
   oSession:CloseRemote()
   // If lSuccess, the file should be downloaded to cLocalFileName.
   // I don't know whether the filename arguments should use / or \ for directory separators.
   ```
2. I think another way is to use the Windows `ShellExecute` function to invoke an external program which downloads the file. I found an example of ShellExecute [here](http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-clipper-visual-objects/125486-execute-program.html). I haven't tried this as I don't have a VO compiler (or help file!) available to me at the moment. I'm not sure whether this is a good way or not, and I don't know whether it's safe from people trying to run a malicious command by supplying a sneaky filename. But I think the following *might* work. It assumes you have the program `curl.exe` (see: [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)) on your path, which is used for downloading the file. You may need the fully path of `curl.exe` instead. I'm not sure where the file will be saved by default (I think you can specify a working directory in the parameter labelled `lpDirectory`)

   ```
   local cParameters as string
   local cURL:="http://www.example.com/interesting.htm" as string
   local cLocalFile:="savefile.html" as string
   cParameters := "-o "+cLocalFile+" "+cURL

   ShellExecute(NULL /*Window handle*/,;
      String2PSZ("open"),;   
      String2PSZ("curl.exe"),;
      String2PSZ(cParameters),;
      NULL_PTR /* lpDirectory */,;
      SW_SHOWNORMAL)
   ```

   See also [the MSDN page for ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
3. There appears to be a method `App:Run(cCommand)` which can be used to start external applications